# on window load events in famo.us app

Tags: javascript, famo.us

Hello I am a noob to famo.us and would like to be notified for events like on window load using the famo.us package

the only way I currently get this functionality, is like this:

```
Engine.on('postrender', function(e){
    console.log('postrendder');
});
```

I could get this by looking at the events emitted by [Engine.js](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/105c8a96582eb1614fe29ecd88a111ed64098153/src/core/Engine.js) in the core package.

The problem I have is this event is emitted for at the FPS of engine which is > 60fps. In other words this event is raised not on window load but as long as the page is alive at >60fps.

How can I get a window load event ?

**UPDATE:**

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449918/what-events-are-available-in-the-famo-us-engine) here shows that you can register for DOM events but when I register for onload or loaded they are not fired.

This can be tested here : [test](http://jsbin.com/jotana/4/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: You are allowed to use normal javascript still - `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ ... });`

Comment: There's a good chance `main.js` is not yet started before the load event is emit.

Comment: so how do i call the onload event? I want a script to start after the entire webpage has been loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Stephen is right. the onload is being fired before main.js invocation. I used this workaround for now.

```
image.on('deploy', function() {
    console.log('post deploy');
});
```

I tied it to a deploy event for a surface.